# I got error when link external library with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I installed [the color-convert library](https://github.com/Qix-/color-convert) via npm but the browser shows me an error message

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined home.js:134
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (home.js:134)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.0.js:5233)
at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.4.0.js:5040)
```

JS

```
var convert = require('color-convert'); // this is line 134
alert(convert.hex.lab('DEADBF'));
```

I think there is a problem with paths?

Comment: This a Node.js library, you should use Browserify or another similar tool to use it in the browser.

Comment: Node has inbuilt support for require,for client side you have to use some libraries to use require

Comment: @ShubhDixit ok can tell me how I can fix it ?

Comment: @polomy They just did

Comment: @polomy take a look at CommonJS, RequireJS, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require()` isn't a function provided by your browser, and is more of a sign that this source code is a *common JS module*.

In order to use a common JS module, you first need to run your source through a program that *bundles* the source, sorta replacing each `require('other_module')` with the source of the other module, producing a single Javascript source file which can included in your frontend HTML.

Two examples of bundlers are `browserify` and `webpack`.

Comment: Whatever bundler you choose needs to process the frontend source code and produce a Javascript source file that is suitable to be used in the browser.  As it stands, code that depends on `require()` the way your code depends on it, will not work in the browser.  See the browserify documentation for tips on how it's supposed to be used..

Comment: It seems complicated for me because I have experience for two months only in web. anyway there is another like library above library

Comment: An alternative to `browserify` is `requirejs`.  requirejs provides you the option of bundling your frontend code offline, but also provides a mechanism to pull in source at runtime.  Note, however, that this method of requiring modules isn't quite the same as the _commonjs method_ you tried to use.  It's a little more involved, and requires your frontend source to be organized just so on the backend.  I'd strongly recommend learning more about browserify before giving up on it.